# knife client list does not list the workstation

Tags: chef

I have a chef server installed on a CentOS VM anf I have workstation setup on another CentOS VM.

When I run the 'knife client list' I see:
`org-validator.pem` and my workstation does not get listed.

I can successfully fetch the ssl from server on my workstation. I have downloaded the org-validator.pem and the admin.pem on my workstation and placed them correctly. Do I have to run chef-client to generate new keys? Why does my workstation not get listed?

Answer (score 1):

Until you run chef-client, your machine would not have created a "client" in the chef-server.